# RxJava zip that acts on every change from both parents

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I'm working in a GUI and I have multiple types of events that may cause a button to be disabled. I've tried several ways to combine these two Observables, but every solution that I've found has required both Observables to publish an event before a result is produced. For example, in this code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PublishSubject<Boolean> conditionAStream = PublishSubject.create();
        PublishSubject<Boolean> conditionBStream = PublishSubject.create();

        conditionAStream
                .zipWith(conditionBStream, (conditionA, conditionB) -> conditionA && conditionB)
                .subscribe(result -> System.out.println(result));

        conditionAStream.onNext(false);
        conditionBStream.onNext(false);
        //Expected output: false

        conditionAStream.onNext(true);
        //Expected output: false

        conditionBStream.onNext(true);
        //Expected output: true

        conditionAStream.onNext(false);
        //Expected output: false
    }
}
```

But the output I get is:

```
false
true
```

Is there any way to combine to Observables so that they "cache" the last result and react to every change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`combineLatest()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html) which will emit every time any of the combined observables emits. It still needs each of them to emit at least once, but you can add `.startWith()`, to all your combined observables to make sure they have an initial emission.